# ManyToMany relation: data correctly saved but cannot be shown : categories is empty?

Tags: php, database, symfony, twig

in a ManyToMany relation (Advert and Category), the database is filled with the data, but I get this error when I try to show the result in Twig, it says:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

on this line in `class Advert`:

```
public function getCategories(){
    return $this->$categories;
}
```

Here is the Twig page:

```
    <p>
{% if not advert.categories.empty %}

{% for cat in advert.categories %}
  {{ cat.name }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</p>
```

.empty is maybe wrong, I did this :

```
<p>
      {% if listCategories|length>0 %}

    listcat
    {% for list in listCategories %}
      {{ list.name }}{% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
  </p>
```

But the error is the same.

Here is the code :

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$advert = new Advert();
$advert->setTitle('title');
$advert->setAuthor('author');

$listCategories = $em->getRepository('OCPlatformBundle:Category')->findAll();
  foreach ($listCategories as $category) {
    $advert->addCategory($category);
  }
$em->persist($advert);
$em->flush();
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('oc_platform_view', array('id'=>$advert->getId())));

}


public function viewAction($id)
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $advert = $em->getRepository('OCPlatformBundle:Advert')->find($id);

  /*or :
  $listCategories = $em
          ->getRepository('OCPlatformBundle:Advert')
          ->getAdvCategories();
  */


  return $this->render('OCPlatformBundle:Advert:view.html.twig', array(
    'advert' => $advert
  ));
  //or with : 'listCategories' => $listCategories
}

//in the advert repository
public function getAdvCategories(){
    $qb = $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->join('a.categories', 'c')
            ->addSelect('c');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}


class Advert {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    public function getCategories(){
        return $this->$categories;
    }
    public function addCategory(Category $cat){
        $this->categories[] = $cat;
        return $this;
    }
    public function removeCategory(Category $cat){
        $this->categories->removeElement($cat);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```$this->categories;``` instead of ```$this->$categories;```?

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko Thank you very much, it solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `$this->categories` instead of `$this->$categories`. The latter one will first resolve the variable `$categories` and will then try to access a property with a name of that value instead of accessing the property `category`.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller change

```
$this->$categories
```

to

```
$this->categories
```

In yor twig:

```
<p>
{% for cat in advert.categories %}
  {{ cat.name }}
{% else %}
  No categories found...
{% endfor %}
</p>
```